# How to scroll floating-action-menu in framelayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-framelayout, floating-action-button

I'm new in android developing and I would like to make a menu as a floating action button. I will have 10 buttons in the menu and all inside framelayout. The problem is, when I rotate the device, half of the buttons disappeared. How can I scroll through the menu buttons?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menu_red"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:elevation="@dimen/button_elevation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="B1"
        fab:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        />
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
        fab:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="B2" />
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_label="B3" />
 </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Put the framelayout inside of a scrollview.  [edit] your post to include the layout xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scrollview?
Wrap your frame layout with a scroll.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <!--whatever you want in a scroll-->

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Instead of linear layout you can use for example a relative

Comment: yes i tried scroll view but didn't work with framelayout

Comment: It must be a frame layout? Maybe you can change it to a linear or relative. Remember only, that a scroll view must have only one child.

Comment: what you mean with one child? please i think this was the error

Comment: all the floating buttons listed inside the menu button inside framelayout

Comment: I've edited my answer and add an example usage of a scrool